# How to get frames from a component <video></video>

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to get frames from HTML `<video></video>` component in javascript so that I can process them and then output to canvas

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_manipulation#Video_Manipulation

Comment: Did you try any research? A simple [**html5 video to canvas**](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+video+to+canvas) so many tutorials and examples in Google search. We help to fix code issues or advice about something to do with your code. Are you getting errors in your code? Then ask here about that... see: [**How To Ask A Good Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this codepen: [Demo](https://codepen.io/ganmahmud/pen/wMyopY)

```js
var videoId = 'video';
    var scaleFactor = 0.25;
    var snapshots = [];

    /**
     * Captures a image frame from the provided video element.
     *
     * @param {Video} video HTML5 video element from where the image frame will be captured.
     * @param {Number} scaleFactor Factor to scale the canvas element that will be return. This is an optional parameter.
     *
     * @return {Canvas}
     */
    function capture(video, scaleFactor) {
        if (scaleFactor == null) {
            scaleFactor = 1;
        }
        var w = video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
        var h = video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
        return canvas;
    }

    /**
     * Invokes the <code>capture</code> function and attaches the canvas element to the DOM.
     */
    function shoot() {
        var video = document.getElementById(videoId);
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var canvas = capture(video, scaleFactor);
        canvas.onclick = function() {
            window.open(this.toDataURL(image/jpg));
        };
        snapshots.unshift(canvas);
        output.innerHTML = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            output.appendChild(snapshots[i]);
        }
    }

(function() {
  var captureit = document.getElementById('cit');
  captureit.click();
})();
```

Change the video url to: http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4 and you have a live demo example